# How to get iOS device token in flutter app

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to get  device token from the ios app to register it with zendesk app.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication,
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("X__APNS: \(String(describing: deviceToken))")
    }
```

But in ios app this method is not triggering only this method is triggering

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) 
{
  print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    Chat.registerPushTokenString(fcmToken ?? "")
}
```

I tried to get that token via the flutter app using firebase messenging

```
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) async {
    var token = value ?? '';
    print(token);
  
  });
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken().then((value) async {
    var token = value ?? '';
  });
```

but both methods are not helping to get the ios device token in flutter. Is the APNS token equal to the device token ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, APNS token for iOS is same as default token, you can get it by using,

```
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((token) {
      print('This is Token: ' '${token}');
    });
```

Comment: The `getToken` method returns the Firebase FCM token. To get the APNS one, you can call the `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken()` method.