# Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided with an FCM token. FLUTTER - IOS

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am integrating Firebase Push notification in my Flutter project. Push notifications are working fine in Android but I am getting following error when trying to run IOS app:-

[FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM002023] The object <Runner.AppDelegate: 0x2837f4b10> does not respond to -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:. Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided with an FCM token.

Following is my AppDelegate Code:-
`

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    
        FirebaseApp.configure()
      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                  options: authOptions,
                  completionHandler: {_, _ in })
      } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
      }
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
```

`

Trying to integrate Firebase Notification in FLutter App and expecting Push notification in IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to implement `didReceiveRegistrationToken` so that the app will generate FCM token. You can check out this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70768059/20447561).